# How to show a function is negligible?

Tags: computational-complexity, cryptography

Let $neg(x)$ be a negligible function (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negligible_function) for the definition).
Let p be a polynomial function such that
 $p(k)\geq 0$ for all $k>0$.

What can we say about $f = neg(p(k))$? Is $f$ a negligible function? If yes,
 then is there any formal or informal way to check whether a given
 function is negligible?

Answer (score 1):

You should exclude the trivial case of $p$ being a constant function. The precise statement is:

For every negligible function $\mu$ and for every nonconstant polynomial $p$ with positive leading coefficient, the composition   $f = \mu\circ p$ is negligible. Indeed, for every $c>0$ we have 
$$|\mu(p(x))| < \frac{1}{p(x)^c} \tag{1}$$ 
whenever $p(x)$ is sufficiently large. Since $p$ has degree $\ge 1$ and positive leading coefficient, we have $p(x)>ax$ for some $a>0$ and for all sufficiently large $x$. Plug this into (1) to find $\mu\circ p$ is negligible.

For the second question: a function that decays faster than any polynomial will often have a decaying exponential term in it. Look for those. Formally, being negligible is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\log |f(x)|}{\log x} = -\infty$$